# Smiley helper codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter smiley helper and when i click image it insert just simbols like :) in textarea not image I want that it should show image when i click image.
I search on net and find some plugin 'TinyMCE' bt i want to use codeigniter library.
pleasse help me.

```
 <?php $this->load->library('table');

 $image_array = get_clickable_smileys(base_url().'img/smileys/', 'a');

 $col_array = $this->table->make_columns($image_array, 8);

$data1['smiley_table'] = $this->table->generate($col_array);?>  

<?php echo smiley_js(); ?>
<textarea id='a'></textarea><p>Click to insert a smiley!</p>

<?php echo $data1['smiley_table']; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Smiley Helper**

Smiley helper can be loaded using the following code:

> $this->load->helper('smiley');

The Controller

In your application/controllers/ folder, create a file called smileys.php and place the code below in it.

Important: Change the URL in the get_clickable_smileys() function below so that it points to your smiley folder.

```
<?php

class Smileys extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

function index()
{
    $this->load->helper('smiley');
    $this->load->library('table');

    $image_array = get_clickable_smileys('http://example.com/images/smileys/', 'comments');

    $col_array = $this->table->make_columns($image_array, 8);

    $data['smiley_table'] = $this->table->generate($col_array);

    $this->load->view('smiley_view', $data);
}

}

?>
```

In your application/views/ folder, create a file called **smiley_view.php** and place this code in it:

---

```
  <html>
<head>
<title>Smileys</title>

<?php echo smiley_js(); ?>

</head>
<body>

<form name="blog">
<textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="40" rows="4"></textarea>
</form>

<p>Click to insert a smiley!</p>

<?php echo $smiley_table; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

When you have created the above controller and view, load it by visiting http://www.example.com/index.php/smileys/

Comment: thanks for your effort, but my question was how to insert picture instead character.My above code do the same as you have post.

Answer (score 0):

That Smiley Helper uses the symbols to represent the images later when you display the page, that is just how it works. If you want actual images inside the textarea you are probably better off looking at tinymce or another wysiwyg.

Comment: thans for rep
bt there is a function 'parse_smileys()' that replace smiles into images in text area bt it works after reading data not in inserting time can we use it to display image using jquer onkeyup

Comment: It doesn't create them inside a standard textarea field. Regular textaea's cannot display images. The ones you see with images are not simple standard html textarea's.

Comment: You can make a preview area which will show the updated content with smilies.

Answer (score 0):

**parse_smileys()**

Takes a string of text as input and replaces any contained plain text smileys into the image equivalent. The first parameter must contain your string, the second must contain the URL to your smiley folder:

for more detail:
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/smiley_helper.html